# How to remove 'My Approvals' tab from Approval screen (EP503010) in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to remove My Approvals tab from Approval screen (EP503010). But challenge is its not like other pages. This screen built in with some automation steps and conditions. How to remove My Approval tab?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this question. We need to use filter in screen in top corner[image]